# Pre-process my data before do a GBM (Gradient Boosting Machine) algorithm

Tags: r, data-science, data-cleaning

Do I have to pre-process my data before do a GBM (Gradient Boosting Machine) algorithm? (i.e. normalizing, centering, scaling features)

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60950/is-it-necessary-to-normalise-data-for-xgboost

Comment: @molbdnilo sorry for the incorrect tag. I'm new posting questions in stackoverflow, I already changed it.

Comment: @desertnaut sorry for the tag, I already changed and thanks for the link, appreciate it.